# ggplot robust clustered SEs

Tags: r

I am trying to create a coefficients plot with ggplot using the simple command:

```
ggplot(regression1)
```

but the standard errors that are shown automatically are not clustered or robust. My clustered robust standard errors for regression1 are stored as "crse1".

The regression is created with

```
regression1 <- glm(YVAR ~ XVAR), data=finaldata, family=binomial
```

The clustered standard errors are created with

```
crse1 <- coeftest(regression1, cluster.vcov(regression1, finaldata$COUNTRY))
```

and the packages I am using for the ggplot chart are "dotwhisker", "dplyr" and "ggplot2".

The dataset finaldata contains XVAR which is a binary variable (0 or 1) and a continuous variable YVAR.

my dataframe "finaldata" looks as follows:

```
     YVAR CONTROL1        XVAR 
1      NA      6          0  
2       0      5          5  
3       1      5          0  
4       1      6          NA 
5      NA      4          0  
6       0      6          52 
7       1      6          0  
8       0      4          31 
9       0      4          43 
10      1      3          0
```

How can I add those standard errors to the plot instead of the automatic ones?

Thank you very much!

Comment: a reproducible example where you show how you created `regression1` along with all the packages required would go a long way and speed up the time someone posts a helpful answer.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply. The regression is created with ```regression1 <- glm(YVAR ~ XVAR), data=finaldata, family=binomial```, the clustered standard errors with ```crse1 <- coeftest(regression1, cluster.vcov(regression1, finaldata$COUNTRY))``` and the packages I am using for the ggplot chart are "dotwhisker", "dplyr" and "ggplot2".

Comment: could you edit the question to include all this info? Also it would be best if you could reproduce it with an inbuilt data set since we do not have access to `finaldata`.

Comment: @maxjohnson what is meant that you provide a snapshot of the data so others (that want to help) can reproduce your problem (=reproducible example) ... or refer to an inbuilt dataset (e.g. iris, mtcars, ...) with which you can "emulate" what you want to do. As mentioned by missuse even with your edited problem statement, we cannot do anything on our end ...

Comment: Thank you Ray and missuse, I have now added a snapshot of the data. Please let me know if there is anything else I can do to make it easier to understand my issue.

Comment: I was wondering if you know how to solve this issue? Please let me know if I should add more information. Thank you!